# Does r.in.gdal -o reproject the imported raster data to the location projection?

Tags: grass-gis

Does r.in.gdal -o actually reproject the imported raster data to the location projection, or do I need to call gdalwarp to reproject prior to importing?

Comment: Just to make clear, r.in.gdal does NOT reproject. You need to either use gdalwarp, as you mentioned, to do the reprojection before importing, or import into a GRASS location that matches the CRS of the raster, then within GRASS reproject to a different location with r.proj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -o flag override the projection of the file (use locations projection). This option  says to GRASS to not check whether the projection of the file to import is the same as the sector.

But in GRASS GIS, you should not mix layers of different projections in the same sector.

The only way to reproject in GRASS GIS is via **v.proj / r.proj.**

[image][image]

[image]

1. you import your raster in a location/sector A with the same projection
2. you use r.proj to reproject (with nearest, bilinear or cubic interpolation) your raster in the location/sector B with the desired projection